# Image Animate inside stage LibGDX

Tags: libgdx

I needed a picture, animated to show within a `stage`, as I did not know if there was any way to make established, that, while I wonder if this is a good way or is there another more efficiently and created in `libgdx`.
share how to take what I wanted to do:

```
private class ImageAnimate extends Widget{

        private Animation animation;
        private float animationTime;

        private int align = Align.center;

        private int imageX;
        private int imageY;

        /** Crea una imagen animada 
         * se asume que todos los frames de la animacion son de las misma dimensiones
         * Creates an image animate
         * it is assumed that all frames of animation are of the same dimensions.*/
        public ImageAnimate(Animation animation){
            this.animation = animation;
        }


        public void layout () {
            if (animation == null) return;

            float width = getWidth();
            float height = getHeight();

            int imageWidth;
            int imageHeight;

            imageWidth = animation.getKeyFrame(0).getRegionWidth();
            imageHeight = animation.getKeyFrame(0).getRegionHeight();

            if ((align & Align.left) != 0)
                imageX = 0;
            else if ((align & Align.right) != 0)
                imageX = (int)(width - imageWidth);
            else
                imageX = (int)(width / 2 - imageWidth / 2);

            if ((align & Align.top) != 0)
                imageY = (int)(height - imageHeight);
            else if ((align & Align.bottom) != 0)
                imageY = 0;
            else
                imageY = (int)(height / 2 - imageHeight / 2);
        }

        public void draw (Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
            validate();

            Color color = getColor();
            batch.setColor(color.r, color.g, color.b, color.a * parentAlpha);

            float x = getX();
            float y = getY();

            animationTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

            if (animation != null) batch.draw(animation.getKeyFrame(animationTime), x + imageX, y + imageY);

        }

        public void setAlign (int align) {
            this.align = align;
        }
    }
```

pseudo code for usage.

```
Animation animation = new Animation(...);         
ImageAnimate = new ImageAnimate(animation);
ImageAnimate.setBounds(...);

Stage.addActor(ImageAnimate);
```

This code works fine for my purpose but
*my question* is there is to do this and *created in libgdx*, thanks for reading and I hope I explained well

Comment: did you look at this https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation?

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in method. I did something similar to this, but I extended Image and BaseDrawable to add some features and make it more easily interchangeable. I think I may prefer your solution though...so much simpler. It might make more logical sense to move your `animation += ...` to the `act` method. There might be cases where you want to make your stage act at different speeds (like slow-motion) so it would be better to use the stage's delta time.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks for answering, I e been tested and works well for me, if you think it would be good and useful to others, have something similar built into libgdx, one might add some details, and put in the github of libgdx if the creators of libgdx like.

Comment: I guess this is how it should be don, simply extending `Actor` (or in your case `Widget`) and ovverriding the `draw()` method, so that it uses your `Animation`. I think it would be cool to have an `AnimatedActor` in libgdx, but it's not neccessary as it's implementation is not verry complex.

Answer (score 0):

Far easier to extend Image.  Override the act()  to set the texture region of the drawable to the key region.  Then it all just works using the built in draw using all the correct geometry.